# JetBrains IDE и Git pull по произвольному url

Tags: git, phpstorm, webstorm

Как в IDE от JetBrains выполнить git pull, git push по произвольному url?

P.S

Мне в уже имеющийся репозиторий нужно смержить другой репозиторий, для этого вполне подойдет git pull git@url:project но я бы хотел что бы при этом у меня появилось IDE окно для мержа конфликтных файлов. Если выполнить эту команду в консоле, окно для мержа не появляется, его можно вызвать после команды git pull ?

Comment: настрой GIT плагин и проинсталируй GIT клиент на твою операционку, на PhpStorm всё работает

Comment: У меня уже есть подключенный репозиторий, с которым работают команды push, pull и прочие, но куда вписывать git@url:project если мне нужно разово куда то залить или обновиться со стороннего репозитория?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно скачать другой репозиторий внутрь текущего проекта просто используйте `git clone`. JetBrains заметит новый вложенный репозиторий и предложить добавить его как `submodule`.
Если нужно "залить" в неосновной репозиторий, эта ситуация сложнее тем, что в GUI такого нет. Нужно открывать встроенный в IDE терминал и использовать команду `git remote add`. И в дальнейшем, возможно `git remote rm`

**UPDATE:** Но если знать о том, что в `git` есть `branches`, одного репозитория обычно достаточно. GUI Jetbrains рассчитаны на работу с одним репозиторием

Comment: Мне в уже имеющийся репозиторий нужно смержить другой репозиторий, для этого вполне подойдет `git pull git@url:project` но я бы хотел что бы при этом у меня появилось IDE окно для мержа конфликтных файлов. Если выполнить эту команду в консоле, окно для мержа не появляется, его можно вызвать после команды `git pull` ?